# how do you make django decimal field widgets (numberinput) increment differently

Tags: python, django, widget

I am allowing someone to set prices for his pizza toppings, and I have a simple form which is the default DecimalField widget

models.py:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    price       = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
```

forms.py:

```
class ToppingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topping
        fields = ('title', 'price')
```

As of now, the widget allows clicking up or down to increase the price, but it defaults to 0.01, or a penny. This is useless, and I want them to be able to jump by 25 cents at a time. I don't know if I'm reading the wrong github, but the source shows nothing of interest, like a keyword arg to set increments:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py

```
class TextInput(Input):
    input_type = 'text'

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        if attrs is not None:
            self.input_type = attrs.pop('type', self.input_type)
        super(TextInput, self).__init__(attrs)


class NumberInput(TextInput):
    input_type = 'number'
```

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you can do this by adding the `step` attribute to the `NumberInput` widget.

```
class ToppingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topping
        fields = ('title', 'price')
        widgets = {
            'price': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'step': 0.25}),
        }
```

Comment: a few subquestions please: how did you know that? the django widgets docs doesn't list that keyword

when I step up it goes to 0.50, 0.75, 1, ...2, ...3, I want it to look like a price. Do you know how to force 3.00, 4.00, etc?

Comment: The `attrs` keyword is a dictionary of html attributes. The `NumberInput` widget when rendered into html is an input element with type number and `step` is one of the acceptable attributes for such input type. As for forcing it to show 2 decimal places, I think you can use javascript to do that. Also, the `attrs` keyword is in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-instances).

Comment: when I use this Widgets ={widgets = {
            'price': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'step': 0.25}),
        }} format       I'm getting an error ==> self.input_type = attrs.pop('type', self.input_type)
TypeError: pop() takes no arguments (2 given)

Answer (score 0):

@codyc4321
Two Decimal places, define it in `models.py`:

```
YOUR_VAR = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=4, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: This is already present  in  `model.py` given as part of the question.